# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery, using Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, isparta

I'm new to webpack, but I started using it in one of my projects to learn about it.

I would like to use jQuery with Bootstrap, however, when I launch the app, I'm getting the following error:

> bootstrap.min.js?5802:6Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

In my webpack config, I have defined two entry points, one for libraries of the project and one for the external ones, called vendors, like jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.

In vendors, I have defined the Bootstrap library after the jQuery library, but I cannot get rid of the error. Any clues of what I'm missing?

This is my webapp config:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
let node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';

export default {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'jquery': node_dir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'jquery-validation': node_dir + '/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js',
      'bootstrap': node_dir + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    }
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.

  entry: {
    // must be first entry to properly set public path
    app: ['./src/webpack-public-path',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      './src/index'],
    vendors: ['jquery','jquery-validation','bootstrap']
  },
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src`, // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
                                //template: 'src/index.ejs',
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jquery: "jquery",
      "windows.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js', Infinity)
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss', 'sass?sourceMap']}
    ]
  },
  postcss: ()=> [autoprefixer]
};
```

And this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dario-webapplication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Webapplication for Dario project",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node tools/nodeVersionCheck.js",
    "setup": "node tools/setup/setupMessage.js && npm install && node tools/setup/setup.js",
    "remove-demo": "babel-node tools/removeDemo.js",
    "start-message": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "prestart": "npm-run-all --parallel start-message remove-dist",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
    "test": "mocha tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\" --reporter progress",
    "test:cover": "babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover --root src --report html node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --require ./tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\" --reporter progress",
    "test:cover:travis": "babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover --root src --report lcovonly _mocha -- --require ./tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\" && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "open:cover": "npm run test:cover && open coverage/index.html"
  },
  "author": "Francisco Jose Parra Gonzalez",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.15.1",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "react": "15.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.30.3",
    "react-dom": "15.3.0",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-router": "2.6.1",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.4.0",
    "babel-cli": "6.11.4",
    "babel-core": "6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "6.11.6",
    "browser-sync": "2.14.0",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.2.0",
    "coveralls": "2.11.12",
    "cross-env": "2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "2.4.1",
    "eslint": "3.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.0.0",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.14",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
    "isparta": "4.0.0",
    "mocha": "3.0.1",
    "mockdate": "1.0.4",
    "node-sass": "3.8.0",
    "npm-run-all": "2.3.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "0.9.1",
    "prompt": "1.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.3.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.3",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "4.0.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.5",
    "sinon-chai": "2.8.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.12.2",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I finally got rid of the error just by adding a new entry in the ProvidePlugin:

```
 jQuery:"jquery"
```

so finally the plugin looks like this:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jquery: "jquery",
  "window.jQuery": "jquery",
  jQuery:"jquery"
})
```

I leave it here in case someone else faces the same problem.

Comment: You don't even specify which file that is! There is no `ProvidePlugin` anywhere in my entire project.

Comment: lol.. same happened with me. add this code block under module.exports in webpack.config.js file.

Answer (score 14):

Using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) you can import like this:

```
import 'jquery/src/jquery';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min';
```

note: This is for jQuery 3.*

Comment: You don't specify which file that is. What if we are using Rails with Webpacker?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap requires jquery to be available on the global object. Try the below -

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min');
```

This is verified for `bootstrap@3.3.7` and `jquery@2.2.4`.

Ref - [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5542#issuecomment-432298925)

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the [Expose Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader) package:

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

And use in your webpack entry point (ie. `main.js`) like this:

```
import 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery'

// ...
```

Comment: require("expose?jQuery!jquery");
require("expose?Tether!tether");

Comment: or import 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery!jquery'