# Importing jquery before bootstrap in angular

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

No matter what I do, I cant seem to get jquery imported before bootstrap wants to use it.

Here is my app.js

```
// JQuery libary needed for bootstrap
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';

// Bootstrap libary
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';

// Bootstrap-select libary 
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css';
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js';

// Angular-material standard CSS 
import 'angular-material/angular-material.css';
```

And here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.4",
    "angular-translate": "^2.15.1",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "^2.15.1",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "^2.15.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

But when I run my page it says:

```
bootstrap.js?f974:8 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.bundle.js:1094), <anonymous>:8:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:1094)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:20)
```

Comment: import * as $ from 'jquery'; Or import * as $ from jquery/dist/jquery.min.js   //Just looked into some starter projects, they mostly define it somehow like this. This is no answer just a hint what I found.

Comment: @Doomenik im definately gonna give that a try

Comment: Naaa, same result :-(   The only way I can get this to work is if I include it directly in the HTML page - all the others import just fine, its only jquery that is the problem

Comment: I completly forgot to ask, do you use angular cli ? If yes add it in the angular-cli.json under scripts

Comment: I dont think so - I use Angular 1.6 and webpack - so im not sure if that has angular-cli?

Comment: Inside of your package.json you have normaly something like devDependencies, if you use cli it would be in there. Try, also import * as jquery from 'jquery' or  import * as jquery from jquery/dist/jquery.min.js (Just to be sure its not based on this"

Comment: Tried all of them, and no I dont use CLI.  For now I just  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>` in the main index.html file - just a bit stupid cause it works fine with all the other script libs.  Very strange!!

Comment: Have you confirmed that jQuery is being imported at all? Also I found this in another SO question, not sure if it will help `import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';`

Comment: @Lewk yes it is imported just fine - I tried removing bootstrap js and then calling some jQuery stuff from inside my pages.  My best guess here is that even if you import jQuery long before you import bootstrap, it is never "fast enough"

Comment: eventually this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063396/error-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-using-webpack  same like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778884/webpack-bundle-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery